# Check if value in list except for number between {}

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
list = ["Hat({})A", "Tie({})B", "Disk({})C"]
```

And another list:

```
inventory = ["Hat(1)A", "Hat(43)A", "Shirt(23)E", "Tie(2)B"]
```

In python, I want to iterate inventory for each item, if it contains the value except for the number, return true. If not, return false.

```
"Hat(1)A", "Hat(43)A", "Tie(2)B" = TRUE
"Shirt(23)" = FALSE
```

Anyone know how this can be done? I've tried everything  and I'm stuck :(

Comment: where does `list = ["Hat({})A", "Tie({})B", "Disk({})C"]` come from? what about `Tie(2)C` would that be true or false?

Answer (score 0):

First you remove the curly braces from the list.

```
l = ["Hat({})A", "Tie({})B", "Disk({})C"]

new_list = [''.join(x.split('{}')) for x in l]

# ['Hat()A', 'Tie()B', 'Disk()C']
```

Your inventory is:

```
inventory = ["Hat(1)A", "Hat(43)A", "Shirt(23)E", "Tie(2)B"]
```

To find the numbers in inventory use **re**:

```
indices = re.findall(r'\d+', ''.join(inventory))

# ['1', '43', '23', '2']
```

Now, you have the corresponding numbers which were present in inventory in indices

```
new_inventory = [''.join(inventory[x].split(indices[x])) for x in range(len(indices))]

# ['Hat()A', 'Hat()A', 'Shirt()E', 'Tie()B']
```

Finally, you can iterate over new_inventory to find if they are present in new_list:

```
[x in new_list for x in new_inventory]

# [True, True, False, True]
```